# How to avoid temporary table on group by with join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having two tables say(for example), **Department** and **Members**

**Department** table description:

```
 CREATE TABLE `Department` (
                           `code` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
                           `name` char(100) DEFAULT NULL,
                           KEY `code_index` (`code`), 
                           KEY `name_index` (`name`) 
 )
```

**Department** table values:

```
+------+-------------+
| code | name        |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | Production  |
|    2 | Development |
|    3 | Management  |
+------+-------------+
```

**Members** table description:

```
CREATE TABLE `Members` (
                        `department_code` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `name` char(100) DEFAULT NULL,
                        KEY `department_code_index` (`department_code`),
                        KEY `name_index` (`name`)
)
```

**Members** table values:

```
+-----------------+----------------+
| department_code | name           |
+-----------------+----------------+
|               1 | Ross Geller    |
|               1 | Monica Geller  |
|               1 | Phoebe Buffay  |
|               1 | Rachel Green   |
|               1 | Chandler Bing  |
|               1 | Joey Tribianni |
|               2 | Janice         |
|               2 | Gunther        |
|               2 | Cathy          |
|               2 | Emily          |
|               2 | Fun Bobby      |
|               2 | Heckles        |
|               3 | Paolo          |
|               3 | Mike Hannigan  |
|               3 | Carol          |
|               3 | Susan          |
|               3 | Richard        |
|               3 | Tag            |
+-----------------+----------------+
```

I want to get the all the department code and name for the given set of users. As i just want the department names alone, I used the below query.

```
mysql> select Department.code, Department.name, Members.department_code from Department left join Members on (Department.code=Members.department_code) where Members.name in ('Rachel Green', 'Gunther', 'Paolo') group by Department.code;
+------+-------------+-----------------+
| code | name        | department_code |
+------+-------------+-----------------+
|    1 | Production  |               1 |
|    2 | Development |               2 |
|    3 | Management  |               3 |
+------+-------------+-----------------+
```

This works fine and the "**explain**" gives me below execution plan.

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys                    | key                   | key_len | ref                  | rows | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Department | NULL       | ALL  | code_index                       | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                 |    3 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Members    | NULL       | ref  | department_code_index,name_index | department_code_index | 5       | test.Department.code |    1 |    16.67 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

But the "**group by**" uses temporary table which may degrade the performance if the **Members** table contains a lot of rows. Though I guess some ideal indexing would help out here, i can't get the proper idea. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like MySQL code and explain, so I removed the SQL Server tag.

Comment: Selecting the `members.department_code` doesn't really make any sense, since it will always match the `department.code`; in any case, you should be using `SELECT DISTINCT` in these situations. `GROUP BY` would be more appropriate if wanted to get how many members were a part of each department, using COUNT().

Comment: i assume you want to ask MySQL for the unique Departments where Members with the `'Rachel Green', 'Gunther', 'Paolo'` names work? As the invalid `GROUP BY` usage made the whole resultset iffy..

Comment: `GROUP BY ` is meant to be used with aggregation.  If you don't have any aggregation, what's the point of `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Try to learn to write proper query.  Any other dbms system (except MySQL) will not even run your query.

Comment: @Eric Consider if two members are available in the department 'Production', in such case if I don't use 'group by', then the row having 'Production' department will be there twice right(one for each member).

Comment: @Selluboy that is what the DISTINCT I suggested in my comment is made for; also, unrelated to that, `LEFT JOIN` becomes an `INNER JOIN` when your `WHERE` conditions require the table on the right hand side of the join to have a match.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the `group by` over all the data using a subquery:

```
select d.code, d.name, d.department_code
from Department d
where exists (select 1
              from Members m
              where d.code = m.department_code and
                    m.name in ('Rachel Green', 'Gunther', 'Paolo') 
             );
```

With an index on `members(department_code, name)`, this should be much faster.

Comment: it should be m.name